# Why do flights approaching Kabul seem to take a different route since the Taliban took over?

Tags: air-traffic-control, landing, approach, routing

From [a reporter on Twitter](https://twitter.com/stephglinski/status/1445731289110351875):

> Nerdy question but genuinely curious:
> All fights into Kabul would previously approach from the east, flying towards the direction of Nangarhar, then making a U-turn over the Surobi basin, then descending westwards into Kabul. Now they seem to all approach via Logar, meaning they descend south of Kabul,then making a smaller left-turn into the airport. It's much faster that way of course so that's great (Herat-Kabul flight time was 45 mins only compared to over 1h before).
> Any particular reason for the switch in flight path? V curious!

Source: [@stephglinski](https://twitter.com/stephglinski)

Comment: The question you are better off asking is why is that happening since the coalition forces pulled out.

Comment: Not familiar with the area, but perhpas certain parts of the airspace were permanently reserved for military operations before the US left. Now that those operations came to an end, there is more airspace available for optimising routing.

Comment: "All flights" suggest the new government has changed the approach procedures for the airport.